# SQL: Sum of multiple rows to update initial table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sum

The below keeps giving me errors, I have worked out it's the group by however I have no indication of what is wrong/ how to fix.

```
t1

    c1 c2

    1 -

    2 -

t2

    c1 c2

    1 - 3

    1 - 2

    2 - 2

    2 - 2

    UPDATE T1 a, t2 b SET a.c2 = sum(b.c2)
    GROUP BY b.c1 HAVING b.c1 = a.c1;
```

Comment: You didn't `JOIN` the table , what is their link id ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE T1
SET c2 = (SELECT SUM(c2) FROM T2 WHERE c1 = T1.c1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
UPDATE a SET a.c2 = sum(b.c2)
FROM T1 a INNER JOIN t2 b ON a.c1 = b.c1     
GROUP BY b.c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
      UPDATE T1
      set a.c2= b.c2 from T1 a inner JOIN 
     (select c1, sum(c2) from T2 group by c1) b on a.c1 = b.c1;
```